# Calling Pardiso 6 in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, blas, intel-mkl, pardiso

I'm trying to use Pardiso 6 sparse solver library in Python. The problem is that I can't seem to load the Pardiso shared object (SO). Here's the error that I get when calling

```py
import ctypes
pardiso = ctypes.CDLL(pardiso_so_address)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    pardiso = ctypes.CDLL(lib720)
  File "/home/amin/anaconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so: undefined symbol: sgetrf_
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

---

PS. I already contacted Pardiso developers and they told me that I need to link against optimized BLAS, but I already have MKL installed via `conda`.

---

**Update 1**: I installed `mkl` via `conda`, but it didn't help. Strangely, I added `import scipy` to the header and the error went away. The same thing happens if I add `import mkl`. So, for some reason, unless `scipy` or `mkl` are manually imported, the `.so` doesn't know that a `lapack` installation exists. Anyway, now another error is thrown, which I think might be related the `libgfortran` library. Here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    pardiso = ctypes.CDLL(lib720)
  File "/home/amin/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_close
```

I double-checked to see if `libgfortran` is installed, and indeed it is:

```
(test) PyPardisoProject$ ldconfig -p | grep libgfortran
    libgfortran.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5
    libgfortran.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4
```

I think something similar might be at play, i.e. the library is there but it needs to be triggered (similar to what `import scipy` seems to have done for `liblapack`, but I have no idea how I can trigger it.

**Note**: I found an example in C on Pardiso website and tested the `.so` file against it via

```
$ gcc pardiso_sym.c -o pardiso_sym -L . -lpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64 -llapack -fopenmp -lgfortran
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./pardiso_sym
```

and it worked with no problem (with the existing libraries on my machine). So, the `.so` works, it's just that I don't know how to inform it of its dependencies in Python.

**Update 2**: Here's the output of `ldd pardiso_sym`:

```
Scripts$ ldd pardiso_sym
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7e982000)
    libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so (0x00007f326802d000)
    liblapack.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007f3267976000)
    libgfortran.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4 (0x00007f3267795000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f326775b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3267568000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3267545000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f32673f6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f32685df000)
    libblas.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f3267389000)
    libgfortran.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007f32670e9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f32670cf000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f3267083000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f326707d000)
```

So, I added the common path, i.e. `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `/lib64` to `PATH` and ran the Python script again via:

```
PATH=$PATH:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib64 python padiso_script.py
```

but the same error is thrown. I also tried adding to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well, but didn't work either.

Comment: What's is output of 'ldd pardiso_sym'? All paths should be available when running from Python.

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot Please see update 2 in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is, rather than adding the location of dependencies to system `PATH`s, you need to explicitly load the dependencies, i.e. `lapack`, `blas`, and `gfortran` in the Python script prior to loading the Pardiso library. Also, it's essential that you explicitly pass the optional `mode=ctypes.RLTD_GLOBAL` argument to `ctypes.CDLL` method in order to make the dependencies globally accessible and hence, Pardiso can access them.

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

shared_libs = ["lapack", "blas", "omp", "gfortran"]
for lib in shared_libs:
    # Fetch the proper name of the dependency
    libname = ctypes.util.find_library(lib)
    # Load the dependency and make it globally accessible
    ctypes.CDLL(libname, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
# Finally, load the Pardiso library
pardiso = ctypes.CDLL(pardiso_so_address)
```

In my experience, if you are inside a `conda` environment with `mkl` installed, you only need to list `gfortran` as dependency and the rest are automatically loaded and accessible, in which case set `shared_libs = ["gfortran"]`.

Answer (score 1):

`Pardiso 6 sparse solver` depends on Lapack functions at least [`sgetrf`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/ddc/group__real_g_ecomputational_ga8d99c11b94db3d5eac75cac46a0f2e17.html), that computes an LU factorization of a general M-by-N matrix A using partial pivoting with row interchanges.

From what we read, `libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so` is linked dynamically against a shared Lapack library. You need to provide a PATH containing one implementation.

Before launching Python, I would recommend you to play with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and include the path to the BLAS/Lapack library you are using. It can be the netlib implementation, the ATLAS implementation or the MKL implementation.

```sh
LD_LIRARY_PATH=$LD_LIRARY_PATH:/my_path_to_lapack \
python -c"import ctypes; pardiso = ctypes.CDLL(pardiso_so_address)"
```

If you use [`conda`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mkl), you can install with the command

```sh
conda install -c anaconda mkl
```

In this case, the installation may directly solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did as you suggested. I've updated the question accordingly. I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Pardiso 6 and Intel MKL Pardiso are not compatible as they have different API. You may try to remove MKL from your systems paths, add OpenBLAS, and try to link your example once again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How can I remove MKL from system paths? In which paths is MKL stored? Btw, shouldn't I still be able to load the `.so` file? I'm not yet calling any API, I'm just loading the `.so` file via Python `ctypes` library.